# (R) when making table, not in alphabetical order, but in the original order

Tags: r

I asked question "Do you agree~?" and
used rating scale "strongly agree" "agree" "neutral" "disagree" "strongly disagree"

When I make table in R using

```
>table(question1)
```

It shows like

```
agree   disagree   neutral   strongly agree   strongly disagree
40      15         45       30               22
```

but I want to see it in the original order like

```
strongly agree   agree   neutral   disagree   strongly disagree
30               40      45        15         22
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to `factor` with `levels` as original order.

```
table(factor(question1, levels = unique(question1)))
```